# How to receive TCP packets without using terminator or fixed length message

Tags: tcp, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration 2.0.3 with TCP. Application behavior is, it is acting as the TCP client and sending a message to the third-party tool using TCP.  So application makes the connection to a third party tool using TCP, sends the message, waits for the reply and when that is received  (again acting as the client) will close the connection. Now the issue is third-party tool can neither add any terminator nor make fixed length message.

As per my understanding, there are three ways to make a packet and send it to application 
1)Always send fixed-sized messages
2)Send the message size with each message
3)Use a marker system to separate messages

But I cannot use any way mentioned above, I want to know how my application can receive the response message in this scenario, Is it possible?

Comment: TCP is a *streaming* protocol. It doesn't have message boundaries, beginnings or ends, unless you add those things to the application protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Is *your* program supposed to close the connection once you have received the message? Or is the *other* program supposed to close the connection once it has sent the message to you?

If the latter then it's no problem since you just read until the connection is closed.

If the former, and you can't alter the application protocol and it doesn't already specify these things (is there a specification anywhere?), then wait with a timeout. If you haven't received anything within X seconds consider the full message received and close the connection.

Comment: See `ByteArrayRawSerializer` and its `treatTimeoutAsEndOfMessage`.

Comment: Using timeouts to delimit messages is rather dangerous, unless it's relatively long (which is not very friendly since the client is waiting for a reply); network glitches can cause incomplete messages to be received. Such activity is not a proper use of TCP. There must be some way that the server knows the message is complete; if so, you can provide a custom `Deserializer` to examine the bytes as they are read from the stream.

Comment: The application is supposed to close the connection once it is received the response message, or the timeout occurs.

Comment: As I am using tcp-outbound-gateway with single-use="true", but per the comments, this class is for adapters not for a gateway.  Comment is "socket must be closed to indicate message end, this (de)serializer
 * can only be used by uni-directional (non-collaborating) channel adapters, and 
 * not by gateways."

Comment: As channel is used for one message only(single-use="true") and the moment response is received channel will be closed. Is there a way we can read entire message byte by byte and where it is end consider that as a end of message, Because timeOut is not a good option, there will be a performance hit due to timeout approch. @Gary can you please suggest the best solution for this problem and it would be great if there is example for same.

Comment: Also application is using spring Integration version 2.0.3 and it  does not have treatTimeoutAsEndOfMessage parameter,as it came in spring-integration since 4.2.2

Comment: 2.0.3 is ancient (> 7 years old) and is not longer supported, but there is nothing stopping you from writing your own deserializer. `>is there a way we can read entire message byte by byte and where it is end consider that as a end of message`. No; as I explained, you must use a custom deserializer and there must be something in the data that allows that deserializer to know that the message is complete. You need to explain exactly what the data looks like (in both directions).

Comment: Thanks, Gary for your inputs, I have used CustomSerializer but somehow not able to receive messages if a terminator is missing, surely I am missing something, I will check that. Apart from this in the message, there is nothing which indicates its end of a message, neither terminator nor fixed length/fixed field.